# I got `Uncaught TypeError: _this.ref.querySelector is not a function` while using semantic ui react dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using [the dropdown menu Floation](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-floating) component, but I got this error

> Uncaught TypeError: _this.ref.querySelector is not a function

here's the full error stack:

[image]

and here's my code

```
<Button.Group color="teal">
  <Button>Save</Button>
  <Dropdown
    as={Button}
    className="icon"
    options={[
      { key: 'edit', icon: 'edit', text: 'Edit Post', value: 'edit' },
      {
        key: 'delete',
        icon: 'delete',
        text: 'Remove Post',
        value: 'delete',
      },
      { key: 'hide', icon: 'hide', text: 'Hide Post', value: 'hide' },
    ]}
    trigger={<div ref={ref => (this.input = ref)} />}
  />
</Button.Group>
```

Comment: Not sure, whether it solves your problem, but the trigger should be written as `trigger={<div ref={ref => {this.input = ref}} />}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem:

I was using `v0.83` and after **updating** to the latest version `0.86` everything works fine.